# Assign dates from datepicker to button as data-id attribute for jquery post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datepicker

i am currently stuck. I want to assign 2 dates from 2 `datepicker` as `data-date1` and `data-date2` attributes to a `button`. Then on click of that button it will do a post call to check against the db with the values from its data attributes.

The php piece of the ajax isn't my problem, more like how do i fetch the datapicker values?

Below is my code so far and here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3837dhxy/2/)

`

```js
$('#date1').on('changeDate', function(a) {
var Date1 = $('#date1').val();
var Date2 = $('#date2').val();
$('#button').attr('data-date1', Date1);
$('#button').attr('data-date2', Date2);
});
});

$(document).on("click", "#button", function() {
  var d1 = $(this).data('date1');
  var d2 = $(this).data('date2');
  $.post('phpurl.php/controller', {
    d1,
    d2
  }, function() { /* do something */ });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>Date 1</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="datetime-local" id="date1">
</div>
<div>
  <label>Date 2</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="datetime-local" id="date2">
</div>
```

`

Comment: actually no, i dont. Hmm.. i have used a wrong term right?

Comment: it's plain bootstrap date picker aka input with `type="datetime-local"`

Comment: Oh!  that's not a bootstrap thing.  That's a html5 thing (https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/datetime-local)   https://jsfiddle.net/ope0aork/  Gotta select all the fields before it logs anything though.

Comment: But it looks like i need to convert this into a string in order to use this as attribute, rather than Object?

Comment: Looks like it is already a string if you change the log to be `typeof this.value`  Also looks like `this.valueAsNumber` returns the date in millisecond form

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

You can assign values from datepickers to button easily using `change` event

```
$('#date1').on('change, blur', function(a) {
var Date1 = $(this).val();
$('#button').attr('data-date1', Date1);
});
$('#date2').on('change, blur', function(a) {
var Date2 = $(this).val();
$('#button').attr('data-date2', Date2);
});
```

```js
$('#date1').on('change, blur', function(a) {
var Date1 = $(this).val();
alert(Date1);
$('#button').attr('data-date1', Date1);
});
$('#date2').on('change, blur', function(a) {
var Date2 = $(this).val();
alert(Date2);
$('#button').attr('data-date2', Date2);
});

$(document).on("click", "#button", function() {
  var d1 = $(this).data('date1');
  var d2 = $(this).data('date2');
  $.post('phpurl.php/controller', {
    d1,
    d2
  }, function() { /* do something */ });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>Date 1</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="datetime-local" id="date1">
</div>
<div>
  <label>Date 2</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="datetime-local" id="date2">
</div>
<button id="button">button</button>
```